# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.String

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I keep getting this error message from the code below. What am I doing wrong?

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

```
var pros = from programs in db.Programs
           select new {
               programs.ProgramID,
              val = (programs.ProgramShortName + " On: " +  (Convert.ToString(programs.ProgramStartDate) ?? ""))
                           };

lbPrograms.DataTextField = "val";
lbPrograms.DataValueField = "ProgramID";
lbPrograms.DataSource = pros;
lbPrograms.DataBind();
```

Comment: What type is `ProgramStartDate`? Can you write that as `((programs.ProgramStartDate != null) ? programs.ProgramStartDate.ToString() : ""` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't recognise `string Convert.ToString(object)`... so... *don't use that*. You *could* try `.ToString()` directly, but frankly I would just select:

```
...
select new {
          programs.ProgramID,
          programs.ProgramShortName,
          programs.ProgramStartDate }
```

and worry about any stringification locally. Or at least a separate projection (noting that `AsEnumerable()` changes this from *composition* to *deferred iteration*):

```
var formatted = from programs in pros.AsEnumberable()
                select new {
                 programs.ProgramID,
                 val = (programs.ProgramShortName
        + " On: " +  (Convert.ToString(programs.ProgramStartDate) ?? "")) };
```

and then bind to `formatted`. This will do a query on the 3 columns, but format locally.

Comment: "... changes this from composition to deferred iteration." — That statement rocks! I've noticed that myself through my sink-or-swim experience in all the "dialects" of LINQ...

MSDN documentation is not very organized lately, can you pin-point to some source for LINQ absolute-master secrets?!